# Are there enough skulls in the game to buy all upgrades?

Tags: orcs-must-die

Are there enough skulls in the game to buy all upgrades? Each level seems to offer only up to five; with a new trap given every level and upgrades costing more than five skulls, it seems like you can never get enough skulls.

Or can you?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Orcs Must Die! has at its core has 19 traps with upgrade costs as follows:

```
#   Trap            Skulls to Upgrade
1.  Spike Trap        8
2.  Tar Trap          8
3.  Boom Barrel      10
4.  Barricade        12
5.  Spring Trap      12
6.  Steam Trap       12
7.  Decoy            10
8.  Brimstone        12
9.  Spore Mushrooms  16
10. Coinforge        18
11. Arrow Wall        8
12. Wall Blades      14
13. Push Trap        10
14. Grinder          16
15. Pounder          14
16. Swinging Mace    16
17. Autobalista      16
18. Archer Guardian  14
19. Paladin Guardian 14

Total               228
```

There are 24 levels in OMD! with 5 skulls for warmage and 5 more skulls for Nightmare so 240 skulls. **Yes, in the base game of Orcs Must Die!, there are enough skulls to buy all upgrades.**

The Artifacts of Power DLC adds:

```
#   Trap            Skulls to Upgrade
20. Shock Zapper     16
21. Floor Scorcher   16

New Total           260
```

With the Artifacts of Power DLC, as 260>240, **no, in Orcs Must Die! with the Artifacts of Power DLC alone, there are not enough skulls to buy all upgrades.**

The Lost Adventures DLC adds:

```
#   Trap            Skulls to Upgrade
22. Mana Well        18

New Total           278
```

The Lost adventures also adds 5 more levels so 50 more skulls, meaning 290 total skulls. So, **yes, in Orcs Must Die! with the Lost Adventures DLC, there are enough skulls to buy all upgrades with or without the Artifacts of Power DLC.**

Answer (score 6):

It is possible, but you have to essentially beat the game twice to do it. You have to play through once on War Mage, and then again on Nightmare.

As further backup, [a quote from the developer:](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2169151&page=2)

> To upgrade every trap, you have to five-skull every War Mage and every
>   Nightmare level. You can get around half of them upgraded by the end
>   of the War Mage campaign, so pick the ones you'll use the most.

I haven't played any of the DLC, though, so if you are including that it's possible that this answer changes depending on how many new traps versus new levels are introduced.